# OneTrust getGeolocationData object is empty for country code "IN"

Tags: cookies, banner, one-trust

OneTrust getGeolocationData is showing empty even though
https://geolocation.onetrust.com/cookiecon../geo/location returned below result
{"country":"IN","state":"XX","stateName":"XX","continent":"AS"}. Can anyone help here why this is happening?

OneTrust getGeolocationData should returned below result for country code "IN"
{country: 'IN', state: 'XX'}